# php laravel swift email sending problems

Tags: php, laravel-5, swiftmailer

I am trying to send an email threw a laravel controller

this is my code:

```
  $email_sender   = 'endritsheholli@gmail.com';
  $email_pass     = 'blablablablablabla';
  $email_to       = 'endritsheholli.a@gmail.com';

  // Backup your default mailer
  $backup = \Mail::getSwiftMailer();


      try{

         //https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha
         // Setup your gmail mailer

         $transport = (new Swift_SmtpTransport('smtp.gmail.com', 587))
         ->setUsername($email_sender)
         ->setPassword($email_pass);

         $mailer = new Swift_Mailer($transport);

         // Set t

he mailer as gmail
     \Mail::setSwiftMailer($gmail);

     $data['emailto'] = $email_sender;
     $data['sender'] = $email_to;
     //Sender dan Reply harus sama

     $message = (new Swift_Message('Reset Password'))
     ->setFrom([$email_sender => 'EndritSheholli'])
     ->setTo([$email_to , 'endritsheholli.a@gmail.com' => 'ESheholli'])
     ->setBody('Here is the message itself')
         ;
         $result = $mailer->send($message);

      }catch(\Swift_TransportException $e){
         $response = $e->getMessage() ;
         echo $response;
      }
```

the error that is returned is:

Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Swift_SmtpTransport' not found

I have installed the composer package and I have tried a lot of proposals in the internet but I cannot find a solution.

Comment: Try adding a \ before the class name, like you are for the exception. `new \Swift_SmtpTransport`. You'll have to do the same for the other Swift classes.

Comment: How do you include the autoloader? Also, have you run [`dump-autoload`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#dump-autoload-dumpautoload-) after installing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must declare Swift_SmtpTransport in use section or write full namespace of class in your code. For example:

```
use Swift_SmtpTransport;


// other code
```

or

```
$transport = new \Swift_SmtpTransport
```